# How do I remove duplicate unordered sets in a list?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of sets and there are unordered duplicates within each set.  How do I remove those duplicates?

```
stuff = [{"andrea","jessica", "margaret"},
         {"jason","john","janice"},
         {"margaret","andrea","jessica"},
         {"Blippi","CocoMelon","Little Baby Bum"},
         {"Little Baby Bun","Blippi", "CocoMelon"}]
```

I tried frozen sets but had no luck. I tried the `dict` method and got unhashable error:

```
final = list(dict.fromkeys(stuff))
```

I tried making another set and that didn't work:

```
final (list(set(stuff))
```

Comment: Do sets have to be an array of sets? Or can it be a simple array or a single set?

Comment: @user14237286, Perhaps you can show the expected output.

Comment: For example `["andrea","jessica", "margaret","jason","john","janice"]` instead of `[{"andrea","jessica", "margaret"},{"jason","john","janice"}]`? `set()` works on the first one but not the second.

Comment: The expected output should be [{"jason","john","janice"}, {"andrea","jessica", "margaret"}, {"Little Baby Bun","Blippi", "CocoMelon"}]   The order of the names does not matter as long as sets with the same 3 names do not appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following line?

```
final = [set(y) for y in {frozenset(x) for x in stuff}]
```

Comment: @user14237286, you might want to accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Frozen sets do work for this:

```py
stuff = [{"andrea","jessica", "margaret"},
         {"jason","john","janice"},
         {"margaret","andrea","jessica"},
         {"Blippi","CocoMelon","Little Baby Bum"},
         {"Little Baby Bun","Blippi", "CocoMelon"}]

no_duplicates = set(map(frozenset, stuff))
print(no_duplicates)
"""
{frozenset({'Blippi', 'CocoMelon', 'Little Baby Bum'}),
 frozenset({'andrea', 'jessica', 'margaret'}),
 frozenset({'Blippi', 'CocoMelon', 'Little Baby Bun'}),
 frozenset({'janice', 'jason', 'john'})}
"""
```